# How to check if a Spark data frame struct Array contains a specific value

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a data frame with following schema

My requirement is to filter the rows that matches given field like city in any of the address array elements.I can access individual fields like `loyaltyMember.address[0].city`, but i have to check all address array elements to see if any match exists. How can i achieve that in spark sql, i couldn't use array_contains function since the array is of complex type

```
root
 |-- loyaltyMember: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- Name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- address: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |-- addressType: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- city: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- countryCode: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- postalCode: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- street: string (nullable = true)
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I believe you can still use `array_contains` as follows (in PySpark):

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, array_contains

df.filter(array_contains(col('loyaltyMember.address.city'), 'Prague'))
```

This will filter all rows that have in the array column `city` element 'Prague'.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestion, dropping the index braces [] from address array did work.

Comment: Would it work with array instead of 'Prague'?

Comment: `array_contains` documentation: https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.2/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.array_contains.html

Answer (score 0):

This might be useful if you want to check if string is present in array of strings.

```
>>> input_df.show(truncate=False)
+-------+-------------------------------+
|str_col|list_str_col                   |
+-------+-------------------------------+
|spark  |[hive, hadoop, spark]          |
|pig    |[sqoop, hive, bigdata, testing]|
+-------+-------------------------------+

>>> input_df.show
<bound method DataFrame.show of DataFrame[str_col: string, list_str_col: array<string>]>
>>> 
>>> from pyspark.sql.functions import concat_ws
>>> input_df = input_df.withColumn("list_str_col", concat_ws(",", "list_str_col"))
>>> input_df.show(truncate=False)
+-------+--------------------------+
|str_col|list_str_col              |
+-------+--------------------------+
|spark  |hive,hadoop,spark         |
|pig    |sqoop,hive,bigdata,testing|
+-------+--------------------------+

>>> input_df.filter(col("list_str_col").contains(col("str_col"))).show()
+-------+-----------------+
|str_col|     list_str_col|
+-------+-----------------+
|  spark|hive,hadoop,spark|
+-------+-----------------+
```